# Fetch but only get status?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

When a new domain is attached, I made a logic to check whether the domain works normally through fetch.

```
fetch("https://" + domain).then((result)=>{
const isOk = result.status === 200
...
 })
```

However, I thought it would be inefficient to fetch the entire HTML doc through fetch just to check if it works.
How can I get only the status value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can request only the headers, as opposed to the whole page, using the [`HEAD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) method. The server should return the same headers as it would if the `GET` method was used, but no body. You can request this behaviour using the [`method` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#method):

```
fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD' })
```

Comment: Whoa. I thought I knew `fetch` but the HEAD method just blew my mind! +1

Comment: @RoboMop It is not specific to `fetch`, any fully functioning HTTP client should be able to do this, as choice of request method is a part of the HTTP protocol.